# Flutter Futures: Waiting for listener to complete at least once

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I am trying to implement a future return on a function that contains a listener. I want to complete this future when the listener has returned data at least once. I am not using async/await because the listen function is not a future. Hence, my option is the following:

```
static Future listenForConsumption() async {
    Completer completer = Completer();
    try {
      kConsumptionCollection
          .where("userId", isEqualTo: User.current.id)
          .orderBy("consumptionDate", descending: true)
          .snapshots()
          .listen(
        (data) {
          consumptionList = data.documents
              .map((doc) => ConsumptionUnit.data(doc.documentID, doc.data))
              .toList();
          streamController.add(consumptionList);
          completer.complete();
        },
      );
    } catch (err) {
      completer.complete();
      throw (err);
    }

    return completer.future;
  }
```

By using a Completer I am trying to wait until the listener completes. However, the function that calls this one seems not to be awaiting for the future to complete:

```
void _checkForCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      await UserManager.fetchCurrentUser(); //Function waits for this
      await Future.wait([
         ConsumptionManager.listenForConsumption(),
         BottleManager.listenForBottles(),
      ]); //Function does not wait for this

      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
      );

    } catch (err) {
      log("$err");
    }
//...Rest of function
```

Any ideas of what can be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
static void listenForConsumption(
    { @required Function onComplete,
    @required Function onError,
    }) async {
    try {
      kConsumptionCollection
          .where("userId", isEqualTo: User.current.id)
          .orderBy("consumptionDate", descending: true)
          .snapshots()
          .listen(
        (data) {
          consumptionList = data.documents
          .map((doc) => ConsumptionUnit.data(doc.documentID, doc.data))
          .toList();

          onComplete(consumptionList);
        },
      );
    } catch (err) {
        onError(err);
    }
}
```